# How to use pandas on spark notebook (data on dashDB) in python

Tags: python, pandas, ibm-cloud, dashdb

Hello I'm using IBM Bluemix.
Here I'm using an Apache Spark notebook and loading data from dashDB 
I'm trying to provide a visualization and it's not displaying the rows, just the columns.

```
def get_file_content(credentials):

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)


props = {}
props['user'] = credentials['username']
props['password'] = credentials['password']

# fill in table name
table = credentials['username'] + "." + "BATTLES"

   data_df=sqlContext.read.jdbc(credentials['jdbcurl'],table,properties=props)
data_df.printSchema()

return StringIO.StringIO(data_df)
```

When i use this command:

```
data_df.take(5)
```

I get the information of the first 5 rows of data with both columns and rows.
But when I do this:

```
content_string = get_file_content(credentials)
BATTLES_df = pd.read_table(content_string)
```

I get this error:

> ValueError: No columns to parse from file

And then when i try to see the `.head()` or `.tail()` only the column names are displayed.

Does anyone see the possible problem here? I have very poor knowledge of python. Please and thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that works for me. 
I replaced 
`BATTLES_df = pd.read_table(content_string)`

with

`BATTLES_df=data_df.toPandas()`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS=notebook
```

And go to your spark directory

```
cd ~/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/

./bin/pyspark --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_scalaversion:spark_version-M1
```

And you can write following code.

```
import pandas as pd
```